# Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\whois\classes\engine.php on line 336

Tags: php, preg-match, delimiter

```
function processAvailable($used_limit)
{
    // determine matching type
    if (strpos($this->CORE->CONFIG->NAMESERVERS[$this->server][($used_limit ? "limit_keyword" : "keyword")], "!!!") === 0)
    {
        $opposite = true;
        $keyword = substr($this->CORE->CONFIG->NAMESERVERS[$this->server][($used_limit ? "limit_keyword" : "keyword")], 3);
    }
    else
    {
        $opposite = false;
        $keyword = $this->CORE->CONFIG->NAMESERVERS[$this->server][($used_limit ? "limit_keyword" : "keyword")];
    }


    // determine if available
    if (preg_match($keyword, $this->whoisData))
        $this->available = !$opposite;
    else
        $this->available = $opposite;
}
```

line 336 is the where the `preg_match` is and when i put delimiters on top for `limit_keyword` parameters as `/limit_keyword/` i am getting the error below;

Empty regular expression in `C:\xampp\htdocs\whois\classes\engine.php on line 336`

help pls

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$keyword` is not a valid regular expression. Plus I think that's overkill in this situation anyway. You probably should be using [`stristr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php):

```
if (stristr($this->whoisData, $keyword)) // <-- notice the reversed needle and haystack
```